# It's possible to delete some columns from a HBASE table via CAMEL?

Tags: apache-camel, hbase

Camel seem to support only the deletion of the full row not just some columns.

There is any way to get something like "delete table name, row, column name " in CAMEL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible. The camel-hbase component is not intended for deleting columns, but to delete rows (eg entities).

If you want to delete a column then use something else, such as the Java API from HBase.

Comment: thanks. We have override the Hbase component to add the feature and it works